# running tensorflow.net on a macos gives an error

Tags: tensorflow, .net-core

i'm trying to run some basic tensorflow stuff on my macos in .net 7.  this is what my `.proj` file looks like

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="SciSharp.TensorFlow.Redist" Version="2.11.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="TensorFlow.Keras" Version="0.10.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="TensorFlow.NET" Version="0.100.5" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

when i try to run this i get the following error.  i have installed tensorflow on my machine as per the directions https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

> Unhandled exception. System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'tensorflow' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable:
> dlopen(/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/7.0.5/tensorflow.dylib, 0x0001)

this is my basic code